# How to set default data in a table in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, seed

I have a table that I'm going to store units of measurements in and the corresponding category.  For example, "cups, volume" and "ounce, mass".  I only have about 12 measurements I care about, and I want them to be in the database without manually entering them because anytime I want to deploy it or move the code somewhere, I want this to recreate.

So, I figure the best way to do this is to create a csv file with them, and then use rake db:seed.  But I've never done this before so can someone guide me as to how to create this csv, and how to write the seeds.rb file to generate that?  Is this the right way to do it?

---

**SOLUTION:**

```
#db/seeds.rb
require 'open-uri'

#Supply all the units of measurement to be used
Unit.delete_all
open("db/seeds/measurements.csv") do |measurements|
  measurements.read.each_line do |measurement|
    unit, uof = measurement.chomp.split(",")
    Unit.create!(:name => unit, :unit_of => uof)
  end
end
```

Comment: if you only have 12 measurements and will probably not be adding any more, does it make sense to even create a table and store them in the DB?  might be other ways to tackle that.

Comment: you're right I thought it would get messy if i just supplied 12 options though, also i might want to add some functionality in the future that would, for example, once you select a unit of volume all other selects will drop masses, so you can't mix and match volume and mass.  This is the main reason I'm storing them in there, would you suggest another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write the code you'd use to generate them manually and put it in the seeds.rb. You can use normal ruby in that file; so either just write plain `create`'s or load a csv you store in, e.g. `db/seeds/measurements.csv`. To get the path to that file, use `Rails.root.join("db/seeds/measurements.csv")`.

Example:

```
File.open(Rails.root.join("db/seeds/measurements.csv")) do |f|
  # use f here
end
```

Comment: So once I have the csv file, the code you mentioned above would only load the file correct?  How would I populate the db with that data?  iterate through each one and input them in the units table?

Comment: yes, just like you would create any other dataset in your controllers, for example.

Comment: I wasnt able to load the file with Rails.root.join, I had to use open.  The code I used is in the question above.  It works, thanks :).  However, I have an issue with it, those units are being referenced in another table (foreign key), so if I do need to update this table, or if I ever run the rake command again just like that, the id's for each record change, and thus the link with the other table is broken.  How would you fix that?

Comment: You don't use the seeds.rb after initially creating the database. I'd use a migration in that case (or another rake task). Concerning the `Rails.root`: you only get a path from that to use with `File.open`.

Comment: Ah thanks, that makes sense.  About the Rails.root again though, could you give me an example of how you would use that with the above code in my solution update so that I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 1):

There's a file called `seeds.rb` in `db` directory.

You can add your default data in it and when you execute `rake db:seed`, that data will be populated in your database.

Here's an example of how you can add seeds to it.

```
product_types = ProductType.create([
                                   {:name => 'clock',:organisation_id => 1}
])
```